# find the smallest square width but encounter modulo by zero error

Tags: python

I code such a function to find the smallest square of an land

```
def find_smallest(small, big):
    if small == big:
        return small
    else:
        sub_small = big % small
        sub_big = small
        find_smallest(sub_small, sub_big)
```

but it report error as

```
>>> find_smallest(640, 1280)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in find_smallest
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in find_smallest
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

There is not a `modulo by zero` error.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider `find_smallest(2,8)`.

In the first loop you set `sub_small = big % small = 8 % 2 = 0` and `sub_big = small = 2`. Then you call `find_smallest(0,2)`.

In the second loop you then try to do `sub_small = big % small = 2 % 0` which you cant do.